# Is it possible to run function in new thread without export the function into new file?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a function in nodejs that I want to run in another thread.

I don't mean to run a file in another thread with the function init. but to run the function itself in another thread.

Is something like that possible?

```
import { foo } from 'lib';

console.log('in file');

await runInAnotherThead(foo)('arg1');

console.log('aa');
```

Comment: Yes, it's possible. You could run the same file.

Comment: @jabaa without using a file? The worker class that spawns a thread [takes a filename parameter](https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#new-workerfilename-options). I mean, in theory you could serialize a function to a string, pass it via postMessage, and feed it to the function constructor on the other side, but even then you'd need some kind of file to kick off that other thread to post a message to. I don't think that's what the OPs asking for...

Comment: No, I don't want to run the same file.

Comment: @JonSud it doesn't have to be the *same* file, it just has to be a valid Javascript file.

Comment: @JaredSmith Run the same file and use https://nodejs.org/api/worker_threads.html#workerismainthread Then you don't need an additional file for the function.

Comment: The problem is this function depends on other imports.

Comment: @jabaa right, but my understanding of the question was that the OP explicitly didn't want that.

Comment: _"The problem is this function depends on other imports."_ Why is this a problem.

Comment: @JonSud so....? Just import the relevant stuff in that file.

Comment: @JaredSmith "... without export the function into a **new** file"

Comment: Javascript just isn't architected that way. It's inherently single threaded. V8 uses something called isolates. Each webworker exists in a separate isolate. You can't do what you want without destroying that isolation and single threaded architecture.